# PHP - Discover if Debian package exists

Tags: php, linux, unix, package

I want to be able to discover if a Debian package has been installed on our production server, the functionality should be just like [`extension_loaded()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

Can anyone suggest a method? I can only assume I should use `exec()` and parse return value for 'command not found', I'd like to know if there's a safer / better option though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have permission to exec, then you could use one of the following:

```
whereis packagename

apt-cache policy packagename
```

Comment: In this instance I do indeed have access to `exec`, and what I like about using `whereis` instead of my method is if someone were to somehow check is `shutdown -h 0` existed the server would die! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple API for this. It should do something like the following;

- Let php write the wanted packages to a xml file, text file, or database, anything you can read with a shell app, perl app, or whatever.
- On the server level, read out the file, database, check if the package exists and return the value in an output file, database table or whatever.
- read out the output file with php and show it to your user

The drawback of the above proposed solution is that it takes some time, eg. you cannot check for the availability of the package in realtime. If that is actually mandatory, you could write a php script which does not take any input, but reads out the packages that should be checked from a database or a text file, where the values have been extensively tested, eg. using a regex. On this way you're sure a malicious user cannot inject shell commands.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, certainly a valid method, in this case an immediate response would be preferential though. +1